# How to improve quality after putting two videos side by side vertically?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am putting two videos side by side vertically with ffmpeg.

Both of the videos are in high quality.

There is a loss of quality and the output looks very bad after this command:

```
 ffmpeg -i input1t.avi -i input2 -filter_complex vstack output.avi
```

You can see an screen capture of the output movie here:

[image]

Any idea why? How to solve it?

Comment: Probably just need to insert `-q:v N` where N should be a small number, say, between 1 to 10, but you should experiment.

Comment: where do i need to insert it?

Comment: thanks Mulvya, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg will reencode your video, without additional parameters it will use default value resulting in a poor quality. Here's an example with a more modern format and codec:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -i input2 -filter_complex vstack -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

If you need better quality, lower the `-crf` value.